# Get users current location

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, geolocation, location

Have been working on WPF application where users current location had to be identified (it is configurable in settings = no anonymous tracking for private data). Several solutions has been tested.

Alternative number 1 - works fine on different computers, also with VPN is on. Location is tracked based on IP address and everything seems to be good. However downside of this is that it uses external sources, like third party websites for getting IP address and then read that IP address to get the location.

```
public string GetPublicIP()
{
  String direction = string.Empty;
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://website/");
  using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
  }

  //Search for the ip in the html
  // code here

  return direction;
}
```

Alternative number 2 - C# Geolocator class. This works fine with additional JSON file with geolocation coordinates and location data. However on corporate computer `PositionChanged` event is not firing for some reason. Not sure is it blocked somehow. No exceptions, but location is not recognized due to event is not firing. On my personal computer same solution works fine (same Windows version - Windows 10). `Geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;` is also not force firing event every 1 second.

```
private void RunGeoTracker()
{
  if (Geolocator == null)
  {
    Geolocator = new Geolocator();
    Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    Geolocator.MovementThreshold = 100; // The units are meters.
    Geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;
    Geolocator.PositionChanged += this.PositionChanged;
  }
}

private async void PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
  {
     // code here
  }
}
```

Are there are any alternatives, preferably without using any REST API or websites. Preferably using JSON or database for getting location data. I heard there is some PowerShell solution? Can't find examples. I mean basically Latitude and Longitude are needed. All the rest can be already achieved.

Comment: Geolocation is crap. If you use it on my IP address, you get a location over 1000 miles away where the ISP has its headquarters. I could also use a VPN service (very common today), and you may not even be able to get the same continent where I am located. IP addresses have no real physical location.

Comment: For all the down voters... can you at least specify what is wrong in this question? Maybe you can provide some answer or comment instead of down voting or closing it?

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for your comment! I also have VPN on my corporate computer, but at least upper solution is providing me correct IP address. Even though our VPN should give different country as an output. I am not a network expert though.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows-native Geolocator API is limited by the wide variety of states a Windows laptop can be in - airplane mode, location settings disabled in common Windows settings, disabled in application-specific settings, or merely that no data providers are available to the OS (GPS satellites, WiFi triangulation, internet connectivity, OEM hardware and firmware etc.). So, any strategy to use OS-specific Geolocator API is contingent on your application (a) needing high-accuracy GPS fix, (b) involving mobility - e.g a worker driving with their open laptop in a car, or (c) ability to guide the user through UX that helps them get a location fix.
That said, do check if your Geolocator object initialization is done correctly via the steps in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location) - they matter!

IP geolocation has its limitations around VPN users, but it has much fewer ways of failing once you ship the software to real-world PCs and laptops. The following REST API for example will not only auto-detect the device's public IP but also respond with the approximate city-level location, including coarse latitude+longitude.

```
https://ep.api.getfastah.com/whereis/v1/json/auto?fastah-key=<trial_key>
```

The JSON response may look as follows, where the public IP is echoed back to your client application:

```json
{
  "ip": "146.75.209.1",
  "isEuropeanUnion": false,
  "locationData": {
    "countryName": "Australia",
    "countryCode": "AU",
    "cityName": "Canberra",
    "cityGeonamesId": 2172517,
    "lat": -35.28,
    "lng": 149.13,
    "tz": "Australia/Sydney",
    "continentCode": "OC"
  }
}
```

The trick is to use IP location APIs that constantly update themselves as the internet and mobile landscape evolve fast.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the above [Fastah API service](https://docs.getfastah.com/docs/quick-start), so I may be a bit biased here :)